# How to replace hyphen with pipe delimiter

Tags: shell-script, sed

input:

```
abc '-' def
```

expected output:

```
abc '|' def
```

Need to replace hyphen with pipe delimeter . 
i have tried this:

```
sed s/-/|/g
```

but its not working and output is coming

```
abc '' def
```

but I want

```
abc '|' def
```

Comment: I'd expect to see some _unterminated s command_ sed error and `/g: not found` errors with that command as `|` is used for pipes in shells.

Comment: `sed 's/-/|/'` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than properly quoting the expression `s/-/|/g` in the `sed` command, you may also use `tr` for simple transliterations as these:

```
$ echo "abc '-' def" | tr '-' '|'
abc '|' def
```

Answer (score 2):

As already discussed in comments you should put the command for sed in single quotes:

```
sed 's/-/|/g'
```